# How to study in and outs ofOperaring Systems

Tags: operating-systems, filesystems

I want to study operating systems in depth, in particular windows, linux and android OS. What is the best way to get started?

Comment: I'm afraid the question is too subjective. Anyway, you could have a look at the books used in university courses on operating systems.

Comment: If you know any good books please let me know

Comment: You can checkout the Tanenbaum book.

Comment: Android actually uses the Linux kernel as well, so depending on how you define "OS", they are the same OS. Both of them are Open Source, so you can just read the source code. Windows is proprietary, but Microsoft offers Academic Source Licenses for research purposes, so if you are an OS researcher, you can get the Windows source code as well. (E.g. the Xen developers got the source code to Windows and ported Windows XP to Xen.)